# What is a specialization diagram and what is its use?

Tags: uml

Well I know some kinds of UML's diagrams, but I haven't heard about this until yesterday. I found the definition of "specialization" but I can't find anything related to its diagram. Can somebody explain me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specialization is a part of class diagram.
Generalization, specialization and inheritance: http://sourcemaking.com/uml/modeling-it-systems/structural-view/generalization-specialization-and-inheritance